# Sign up using google account

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to add a 'Login using Google' type login page. But I cant find any module that does it out of the box. Could anyone help me proceeding in the right direction as to creating a module that would allow user to sign up with their google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a module called [openid selector](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector) that does exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

After my long trial and error with many modules, I can recommend [Hybridauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) -- the module is maintained and working admirably well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Janrain](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) module and service. The service is [free](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/pricing) for small site

Comment: yes, I am using that as of now, was looking for some options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Google Friend Connect](http://drupal.org/project/friendconnect) module.

> [Google Friend Connect (GFC)](http://www.google.com/friendconnect) provides simple user authentication using any OpenID account, including Google, Yahoo and AIM. Instead of filling in yet another profile form, your users can connect to their existing identities, showing current profile pictures. By making login easier and connected to existing identity, you'll see increased engagement and comment activity.

Comment: I downloaded the module, entered the site id, but there nothing like a 'sign up with google' option. It settings for the friend connect just has a comments and social bar. Is there a way I could just get sign up with google like janrain has? thank a ton!

Comment: It could be a silly question, but can users create accounts on your site? If they cannot create their own account, then the module doesn't add anything to the login form.

Comment: I got it working, but it not exactly what I'm looking for, it doesn't allow to sign up to my drupal site using google account, the google sign up is restricted to the social bar alone and is not drupal-wide.

Comment: Looks like I was expecting too _much_, I'll have to follow the google friend connect api to get the above feature working.

Answer (score 1):

The [OAuth Connector](http://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector) module for Drupal 7 claims to be supporting signing up and logging in through OAuth 2 API:s in general and Google+ specifically.

Comment: Yes, this modules does the job.